# Php session codes not working on Nginx server

Tags: php, session, nginx, server, yii2

This code works on local XAMPP server, but on nginx server it doesn't:

```
if (!empty($old_session_id))
{
    session_id($old_session_id);  #
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
    session_destroy(); #for destroy session
}
```

Comment: PHP versions? How does this have anything to do with yii? Have you checked the logs? Error reporting on? ...

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir /var/lib/php/session
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session
```

Comment: I have already read the from document but not found anything, Please be strict!